# Which Qt function does return HTTP request in string?

Tags: qt, httprequest

I know that I can have some HTTP request, say post , for some webpage with **QNetworkAccessManager::post** function. And all things would be good. But I need the raw request that Qt creates and sends to port 80 of some server. Let me explain, I have a module that I can only create TCP connection with that module to a server. So I can't use Qt classes directly. I have to get the request by some way from Qt and then try to send to port 80. Some thing like this:

```
QString SomeClass::httpRequest();
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're building the request, which it sounds like you are, why not pass the request along to your module?

Comment: Sure. I need that request . Qt hides request from us. I need the request.

Comment: How are you currently generating the request in Qt?

Comment: I want to upload a picture. So I can use post function but I want its http request. Because I want to send it directly to port 80 of some site through a tcp connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in the class QNetworkReply::rawHeader[1], which is returned by post method

1 - http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#rawHeader